# Unable to secure Spring boot management actuator endpoints

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot

I am trying to secure the Spring Boot actuactor endpoints. I have working security on my `/api` REST interface, but trying to add security on the built-in endpoints does not seem to work.

I have set up grouping of the endpoints in my `application.properties`:

```
management.context-path=/management
```

I have this in my Java Config

```
@Override
protected void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception
{
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy( SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS );

    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers( "/api/**" ).hasRole( "READONLY" )
        .antMatchers( "/management/**" ).hasRole( "ADMIN" );


    SecurityConfigurer<DefaultSecurityFilterChain, HttpSecurity> securityConfigurer = new XAuthTokenConfigurer( userDetailsServiceBean() );
    http.apply( securityConfigurer );
}
```

When I use my browser to go to anything below `/api`, I get a 403 back as expected. When going to /`management/info` for example, I see the JSON being returned where I would also expect a 403.

I also tried adding this to my `application.properties` file:

```
management.security.role=ADMIN
```

But that did not help either.

The DEBUG output shows:

```
2014-05-02 10:15:30 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1] ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource - 
Adding web access control expression 'hasRole('ROLE_READONLY')', for Ant [pattern='/api/**']

2014-05-02 10:15:30 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1] ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource - 
Adding web access control expression 'hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')', for Ant [pattern='/management/**']
```

And then why I try the HTTP GET:

```
2014-05-02 10:16:39 DEBUG [http-nio-8443-exec-4] AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/management/info'; against '/css/**'
2014-05-02 10:16:39 DEBUG [http-nio-8443-exec-4] AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/management/info'; against '/js/**'
2014-05-02 10:16:39 DEBUG [http-nio-8443-exec-4] AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/management/info'; against '/images/**'
2014-05-02 10:16:39 DEBUG [http-nio-8443-exec-4] AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/management/info'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
2014-05-02 10:16:39 DEBUG [http-nio-8443-exec-4] AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/management/info'; against '/management/info'
2014-05-02 10:16:39 DEBUG [http-nio-8443-exec-4] FilterChainProxy - /management/info has an empty filter list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log that tells the story is: "/management/info has an empty filter list" because it is explicitly marked as ignored (/info is always supposed to be available). Try one of the other actuator endpoints and see if those behave as you expect. If you really need to secure the info endpoint you can set endpoints.info.sensitive=true (I think).

Comment: Totally correct! The 2 ones I tried are `/info` and `/health` and both seem to be available always. If I use `/beans` for example, I do get the expected 403 back. You can maybe add this info [in the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-sensitive-endpoints)?

Comment: It's there: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-sensitive-endpoints, http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints. If you'd like to suggest further clarifications, please do.

Comment: Indeed, seems I did not notice the `Sensitive` column in the table.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and I'm still not able to secure the sensitive APIs (ex: /env) I'm doing my configuration in application.properties 
management.context-path=/management
management.security.enabled=true
management.security.roles=SOME_ROLE

Should that suffice or is the configuration in the config class necessary?

Comment: You have to add spring security to the classpath?